# Mongo Aggregate Nested Array, Lookup

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am creating a web application using MongoDB and Go, which includes role based access control. I am storing the information regarding this in 2 collections, `permissions` and `roles`.

This is how these two collections look like.
Permissions

```
{
    "operation": "create",
    "resource": "project"
}
{
    "operation": "read",
    "resource": "project"
}
{
    "operation": "update",
    "resource": "project"
}
{
    "operation": "delete",
    "resource": "project"
}
{
    "operation": "create",
    "resource": "user"
}
```

`resource` is something on which an `operation` is performed. So if there is some operation which cannot be performed on some resource, then, I needn't store it. For example user can only be created hence only `create` `user` need to be stored.
Currently there are only 4 operations(create, read, update, delete) in the scope of the application, but could increase, like `upload` could come into picture.

Roles

```
{
    "role": "admin",
    "display_name": "Administrator",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "operation": "create",
        "resource": "project"
      },
      {
        "operation": "read",
        "resource": "project"
      },
      {
        "operation": "update",
        "resource": "project"
      },
      {
        "operation": "delete",
        "resource": "project"
      }
    ]
}
```

Roles contain role, the name of role to be displayed on UI and the set of permissions that role has.

I need to send this information to UI using a REST API in a specific format, which would describe whether a specific role can perform an operation on a resource or not using the `checked` flag and whether a specific operation on a resource is editable or not by using the flag `isEditable`.
For example the permissions collection doesn't contain an operation delete on resource user, so it should not be editable, hence flag is set to false. Similarly user can be created, hence it is set to true.

```
 {
    display_name: "System Administrator",
    role: "admin",
    permissions: [
      {
        resource: "user",
        privilages: {
          create: { checked: false, isEditable: true },
          delete: { checked: false, isEditable: false },
          update: { checked: false, isEditable: false },
          read: { checked: false, isEditable: false }
        }
      },
      {
        resource: "project",
        privilages: {
          create: { checked: true, isEditable: true },
          delete: { checked: true, isEditable: true },
          update: { checked: true, isEditable: true },
          read: { checked: true, isEditable: true }
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to perform this using mongo aggregations? Or do I need to make modifications in my schema, If yes, then what modifications should I make.

Comment: Why don't you just store the desired document into a single collection ? Also, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem in 3 steps:

1. Include all the permissions for every role and add a flag called `checked`. This increased data redundancy but that wasn't a big issue.
2. Do a `group by` on `resource` field in `roles` collection.
3. Populate the missing `privileges` for every `resource` with `isEditable` set to false on server side.

I had to traverse the data on server side, but this was the most efficient way I could think of.